# Normalize a matrix so that its maximum eigenvalue is equal to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to implement Harris Affine Interest Point Detector in Octave.
The step 7 says that `concatenate U(at kth step) = mu(at kth step).U(at (k-1)th step) and normalize U(at kth step) to lambda_max(U(at kth step))=1` where U is a transformation matrix.

Well, I learnt from some links on this site that for normalizing eigenvalues `lambda = [lambda_min, lambda_max]` where `lambda_min` and `lambda_max` are the two eigenvalues (say), the procedure is 
`normalized_lambda = lambda/||lambda||`

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest would normalize the vector of eigenvalues, but since you are not manipulating the matrix itself this couldn't effect the eigenvalues of the matrix.

One way to normalize a matrix such that it's largest eigenvalue is equal to 1 is to divide the matrix by that eigenvalue. If I write the normalized matrix $U$ as $\hat{U}$, this is accomplished by
$$\hat{U} = \frac{U}{\lambda_{max}}$$
This corresponds to what you have found regarding normalization because $\lambda_{max}=\|U\|$, the induced matrix 2-norm. Hence your normalized $\hat{U}$ could be written $$\hat{U}=\frac{U}{\|U\|}$$ which matches the form of the normalization process that you found.